# QThread hungs up when calling isRunning on it

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt4, qthread

I have a `QThread` that fetches data from the web. Sometimes the user asks for something else, and the data needs to be fetched changes as well.

In my current configuration, I call `terminate()` upon the thread, change the input data, and call `start()` on the thread again. Now, that works fine, but sometimes I get the main eventloop stuck when calling `isRunning()` or `isFinished()` upon a terminated thread. It gets stuck forever, and does not recover until I kill the process.

1. Why would `isRunning()` or `isFinished()` hung in the first place? They don't suppose to block.
2. Is this workflow acceptable? If not, how can I stop a thread's process when I don't need it no more (or how can I abandon it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in some cases, the thread becomes unusable after termination, and `isRunning()` and `isFinished()` may hang the calling thread, even if called only after the `TERMINATED` signal.

My workaround was to terminate a thread, forget about it and start a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `terminate()`, read the  warning in the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#terminate).

Whil it is possible to restart a `QThread`, restarting threads usually is not a good idea, there should be a better solution to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: My thread doesn't hold any mutexes. It fetches data from the web and sends it to the main thread through a signal. Killing it anytime is fine, and it doesn't need to cleanup a thing. Plus, killing off threads doesn't suppose to break `isRunning()`'s behavior.

Comment: What about the mutexes held by the QThread itself? I bet [this](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/corelib/thread/qthread.cpp#line465) is where `isRunning` is hanging, but it's hard to say, I can't reproduce it.